# how to separate values in variable from fortokens in jstl

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

I'm stuck on assigning value to a `variable` using `forTokens` of `JSTL`

#### Code

```
<c:forTokens items="${row.date}" delims="/" var="values">
    <c:set var="date" value="${values}"></c:set>
    <c:out value="${date }"></c:out>
</c:forTokens>
```

through the above code I get some thing like :

```
19 April 2014
```

Now I want to know how to get :

> String day = "19"
>
> String month = "April"
>
> String year = "2014"

from `${values}` which is like `Array`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<c:forTokens items="${row.date}" delims="/" var="values" varStatus="status">
    <c:if test="${status.index == 0}">
        <c:set var="day" value="${values}"></c:set>
    </c:if>
    <c:if test="${status.index == 1}">
        <c:set var="month" value="${values}"></c:set>
    </c:if>
    <c:if test="${status.index == 2}">
        <c:set var="year" value="${values}"></c:set>
    </c:if>
</c:forTokens>
```

Comment: above `code` works as I desired. Thanks a lot `Man`, you just saved my life and I'm confused who `down voted` this! :-P

Answer (score 0):

**Updated:**

In JSP I added the following code:

```
<%--You can use your date instead of this--%> 
<%  pageContext.setAttribute("date", new Date()); %>


<fmt:formatDate  value="${date}" pattern="dd" var="day"  /></p>
The day is: <c:out value="${day}"/>

<fmt:formatDate  value="${date}" pattern="MMMM" var="month"  /></p>
The month is: <c:out value="${month}"/>

<fmt:formatDate  value="${date}" pattern="yyyy" var="year"  /></p>
The year is: <c:out value="${year}"/>
```

And it works:

```
The day is: 19

The month is: April

The year is: 2014
```

In my `pom.xml` I have the following dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>


<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: this gives me `javax.el.ELException: Cannot convert 19/April/2014 of type class java.lang.String to class java.util.Date` on `<fmt:formatDate value="${date}" pattern="dd" var="day"/>`

Comment: @SuperUser, please check another approach:
`<fmt:formatDate value="${date}" pattern="dd/MMM/yyyy" var="theDate"/>`

`<c:out value="${theDate.year}"/>` etc.

Comment: `Man` thanks a lot for your time, but sorry the `Other` answer solved my `problem`. Any ways `Happy Coding` ;-)